# How to query for the following SQL Server table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My table is as follows:

[MY TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2F8L.png)

```
ID  SEQNO FREQUENCY
123 0     YEARLY
123 1     HALFYEARLY
256 0     QUARTERLY
256 1     YEARLY
256 2     HALFYEARLY
456 0    QUARTERLY
456 1    YEARLY
456 2    YEARLY
```

My result should have:

[RESULT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw71F.png)

```
ID   OLDFREQUENCY   NEWFREQUENCY
123   YEARLY        HALFYEARLY
256    QUARTERLY     HALFYEARLY
456    QUARTERLY     YEARLY
```

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Please don't use links to images.  Please include your data and expected results as text.  This way the question remains complete even if the links break, etc.  It is also the reason that the question editor has markdown allowing formatting as code, etc.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: 1. mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Looks like there were two requests to clarify the tagging above, and you have not responded to them, despite commenting two hours later. Please be willing to respond to helpful remarks - questions are maintained here even after answers are given. I have downvoted for this reason, and for the begging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
select id,
   max(case when seqcnt = -1 then frequency end) [oldfrequency],
   max(case when seqcnt = 1 then frequency end) [newfrequency]
from (
    --this subquery will create new column named seqCnt, which will be equal to:
    -- -1 when this is the first seqno
    -- 1 if this is the last seqno
    -- 0 in other cases
    select *, case when max(seqno) over (partition by id) = seqno then 1 else case when seqno = 0 then -1 else 0 end end [seqCnt] from @x
) as a
-- we only want first or last seqno
where seqcnt in (-1, 1)
group by id
```

Note, that you have to change `@x` to your actual table name.

Comment: If I have to inner join another table and another column  in the query, how do I do that?

Comment: You have to learn for yourself how to use `JOIN`s. If you have anymore questins, feel free to post another one on this site ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT FQ1.ID, FQ1.FREQUENCY as OLDFREQUENCY, FQ2.FREQUENCY as NEWFREQUENCY
from FREQUENCIES FQ1 inner join FREQUENCIES FQ2
    ON FQ1.ID = FQ2.ID
        WHERE FQ1.SEQNO = 0 OR FQ2.SEQNO = 1;
```

Let me know if it works please.

Comment: I think that it goes an 'AND' in the 'where' clause. Not sure

Comment: The query is returning duplicates and the resulting rows are:
{ 123  YEARLY   YEARLY }
{ 123   YEARLY   HALFYEA }
{  123   HALFYEARLY   HALFYEARLY }

I want only the second row to be displayed

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for advise. Take a look to the @MichałTurczyn response